# Adding background audio for a C# Console Application

Tags: c#, audio, .net-core, console-application

I am writing a C# Console Application in .NET Core and would like to add a .wav or .mp3 file to my Solution and have it playing in the background while my application is running.

I have tried NAudio and System.Media doesn't seem to be available in .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a reference to PresentationCore.dll? Without this you wouldn't be able to use System.Media in .NET core

To do this:
Right click references in your solution explorer
Click add reference and look for PresentationCore

(Hopefully then you should be able to get the System.Media way working just fine)

Comment: I do not see it in there when I go to add it and search for it.

Comment: ask questions in the comments, not in your answers. If comments go unanswered then provide a solution for the most probable case(s)

Comment: Okay......When I go to Manage Nuget packages, it does not list the dll. Is there another way to get this file?